Rank window function not working -showing only ones
The below Rank Window function doesn't work. Rank only gives me ones. I am trying to rank the measure "% Change Quarter" against  'Calendar'[Year] and 'Calendar'[Quarter]:
EVALUATE
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        'Calendar'[Year],
        'Calendar'[Quarter],
    "% Change Quarter", [% Change Quarter],
    "RNK", rank(
    DENSE,
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
            'Calendar'[Year],
            'Calendar'[Quarter],
        "% Change Quarter", [% Change Quarter]
        ),
    ORDERBY([% Change Quarter], DESC),
    PARTITIONBY('Calendar'[Year])
        )
    )
    

Output Below:
|Calendar[Year]|Calendar[Quarter]| [% Change Quarter]|[RNK]
-----------------------------------------------------------
|2023          | Q2              |0.07               |1
|2023          | Q3              |-0.11              |1
|2023          | Q4              |0.57               |1
|2024          | Q1              |0.69               |1
|2024          | Q2              |-0.12              |1
|2024          | Q3              |0.01               |1

What am I missing, is there a problem with my filter context for year and Quarter? Does it need an All filter function, because I tried that with summarizecolumn but it is not working.
The below is the PBIX file:
https://1drv.ms/u/c/1e7368b2a4fe3faa/EdliZDH7XtlItZYYIRZasBABiGHzsp-whGV-q1mqOW0KiQ?e=9bnnii

Can you share a .pbix?

Thanks David, but how do I do that? Like Stack overflow always has rules and rules of posting, I can't post PBIx

Upload to an external site and share a link here

Hi,  tried sending it on wetransfer  and it kept giving me errors, hence the frustration on the previous comment, the below is one drive, hope that is okay?
https://1drv.ms/u/c/1e7368b2a4fe3faa/EdliZDH7XtlItZYYIRZasBABiGHzsp-whGV-q1mqOW0KiQ?e=aj4tJH

Does this do what you want?
EVALUATE

    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        'Calendar'[Year],
        'Calendar'[Quarter],
        "% Change Quarter", [% Change Quarter],
        "RNK", RANK(
            DENSE,
            CALCULATETABLE(SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
                'Calendar'[Year],
                'Calendar'[Quarter],
                "% Change Quarter", [% Change Quarter]
            ), REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar'[Year],'Calendar'[Quarter])),
            ORDERBY(
                [% Change Quarter],
                DESC
            ),
            PARTITIONBY('Calendar'[Year])
        )
    ) 


Flip man, why didn't I think of remove filters?  thank you Davide, it works
